# define a cost function

Tags: calculus

I would like to define a cost function that penalies when the amount of a variable is out of a base. I mean assume that the value of $x$ should be

$a\le x\le b$

now how can I define a single cost function that can penalies when the value is out of this base and equal to $0$ when it is inside the base.

Comment: When you say "single function" do you mean without a case statement?  You can compose two [logistic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) to do that, but the break will not be exactly sharp.  What is the resistance to case statements?

Answer (score 1):

You can define $$cost = \begin {cases} 1,000,000 & x \lt a \\ 0& a \le x \le b \\ 1,000,000 & x \gt b \end {cases}$$

You can avoid the case statement by using the Fourier transform:  let $T=b-a, t=x-\frac 12(a+b)$, so the allowed range is $t \in (-\frac T2,\frac T2)$.  Then a square pulse of height $1$ is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(2i\pi f t)\frac 1{\pi f}\sin(\pi f t)df$ and your function is $1-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(2i\pi f t)\frac 1{\pi f}\sin(\pi f t)df$

Answer (score 0):

A usual approach is to use indicator functions.
Call "$d_a = a-x$" and $d_b = x-b$.
Then
$$C(d) = g_a(d_a)\cdot I_{\{x<a\}} + g_b(d_b)\cdot I_{\{x>b\}}$$

The functions $g_a()$ and $g_b()$ can take various forms, depending on what kind of cost do you want: if the direction of deviation does matter, then $g_a()\neq  g_b()$. If the penalty is one-off, and it does not depend on how far from the boundaries $x$ is, then these functions will be constants.

If the direction does not matter but the distance does, then a usual specification is for the $g$'s to be squares -in this last case they are easily used in stochastic settings also:

$$g_a(d_a) = c\cdot(a-x)^2, \;\; g_b(d_b) = c\cdot (x-b)^2$$